# How to extract some url from html?

Tags: python, html, regex

I need to extract all image links from a local html file. Unfortunately, I can't install `bs4` and `cssutils` to process html.

```
html = """<img src="https://s2.example.com/path/image0.jpg?lastmod=1625296911"><br>
<div><a style="background-image:url(https://s2.example.com/path/image1.jpg?lastmod=1625296911)"</a><a style="background-image:url(https://s2.example.com/path/image2.jpg?lastmod=1625296912)"></a><a style="background-image:url(https://s2.example.com/path/image3.jpg?lastmod=1625296912)"></a></div>"""
```

I tried to extract data using a regex:

```
images = []
for line in html.split('\n'):
    images.append(re.findall(r'(https://s2.*\?lastmod=\d+)', line))
print(images)

[['https://s2.example.com/path/image0.jpg?lastmod=1625296911'],
 ['https://s2.example.com/path/image1.jpg?lastmod=1625296911)"</a><a style="background-image:url(https://s2.example.com/path/image2.jpg?lastmod=1625296912)"></a><a style="background-image:url(https://s2.example.com/path/image3.jpg?lastmod=1625296912']]
```

I suppose my regular expression is [greedy](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy) because I used `.*`?
How to get the following outcome?

```
images = ['https://s2.example.com/path/image0.jpg',
          'https://s2.example.com/path/image1.jpg',
          'https://s2.example.com/path/image2.jpg',
          'https://s2.example.com/path/image3.jpg']
```

If it can help all links are enclosed by `src="..."` or `url(...)`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
import re
html = """<img src="https://s2.example.com/path/image0.jpg?lastmod=1625296911"><br>
<div><a style="background-image:url(https://s2.example.com/path/image1.jpg?lastmod=1625296911)"</a><a style="background-image:url(https://s2.example.com/path/image2.jpg?lastmod=1625296912)"></a><a style="background-image:url(https://s2.example.com/path/image3.jpg?lastmod=1625296912)"></a></div>"""
images = re.findall(r'https://s2[^\s?]*(?=\?lastmod=\d)', html)
print(images)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6IKSVW). Output:

```
['https://s2.example.com/path/image0.jpg',
 'https://s2.example.com/path/image1.jpg',
 'https://s2.example.com/path/image2.jpg', 
 'https://s2.example.com/path/image3.jpg']
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9cmNFZ/1), too.  It means

- `https://s2` - some literal text
- `[^\s?]*` -zero or more chars other than whitespace and `?` chars
- `(?=\?lastmod=\d)` - immediately to the right, there must be `?lastmode=` and a digit (the text is not added to the match since it is a pattern inside a positive lookahead, a non-consuming pattern).

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
indeces_start = sorted(
    [m.start()+5 for m in re.finditer("src=", html)]
    + [m.start()+4 for m in re.finditer("url", html)])
indeces_end = [m.end() for m in re.finditer(".jpg", html)]

image_list = []

for start,end in zip(indeces_start,indeces_end):
  image_list.append(html[start:end])

print(image_list)
```

That's a solution which comes to my mind. It consists of finding the start and end indeces of the image path strings. It obviously has to be adjusted if there are different image types.

Edit: Changed the start criteria, in case there are other URLs in the document

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
xx = '<img src="https://s2.example.com/path/image0.jpg?lastmod=1625296911" alt="asdasd"><img a src="https://s2.example.com/path/image0.jpg?lastmod=1625296911">'
r1 = re.findall(r"<img(?=\s|>)[^>]*>",xx)
url = []
for x in r1:
  x = re.findall(r"src\s{0,}=\s{0,}['\"][\w\d:/.=]{0,}",x)
  if(len(x)== 0): continue
  x = re.findall(r"http[s]{0,1}[\w\d:/.=]{0,}",x[0])
  if(len(x)== 0): continue
  url.append(x[0])
print(url)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).